# Arrangement of the word SUCCESSES such that it spells SUCCESSES

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I'm having difficulty with this problem. I know there are are $$\frac{9!}{4!2!2!}\ $$ possibilities. For determining the favorable outcomes would I do as follows:
4 possibilities for s in first spot, 1 poss. for U, 2 for C, 1 for C...

So, $$ (4)(1)(2)(1)(2)(3)(2)(1)(1)$$ favourable outcomes?

(Each letter is considered distinct)

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is not clear what you mean by "it spells successes"!

Comment: U is fixed.  After that you have $4$ of $8$ remaining letters available for location $1$.  Then $2$ of $7$ and $1$ of $6$ for locations $3,4$, and so on.

Comment: @abiessu so if I understand correctly there are: 8C4 * 7C2* 6C1* 5C2 * 4C3 * 3C2 * 2C1 favorable outcomes

Comment: Um, there is only one way to spell SUCCESSES using SUCCESSES?

Comment: Are you considering each letter distinct? Like, the first 'S' is identifiably different from the second 'S' in such a way that once you permute them, you can figure out their original order? If not, then there is only one possible "favorable" outcome. Out of the $\dfrac{9!}{4!2!2!}$ multiset permutations, only one of them spells "SUCCESSES", as bobeyt6 mentioned.

Comment: @bobeyt6 Each repeated letter is identifiably different so arranging them randomly gives more than one favorable outcome

Comment: @cpsc You should update the problem to reflect that. Currently, you say "I know there are $\dfrac{9!}{4!2!2!}$ [possible arrangements of the letters]." That assumes the repeated letters are indistinguishable, which is what causes confusion. Remove that line, and add in that each letter is distinguishable. Now, there are $9!$ arrangements for the letters, and the answer provided by Mark is correct.

Answer (score 1):

So from what I understand, we wish to spell $S_1UC_1C_2E_1S_2S_3E_2S_4$, where the locations for the letters for which set they are from are fixed. The $U$ is fixed, so there's $1$ way to choose it. For the rest of the leters, we take a particular combination — like the one listed above — and just count the possibilities there are if we rearrange the letters in amongst themselves. That is, we have $4!$ ways to arrange the $S_i$ amongst themselves, and $2!$ ways to arrange the $C_i$ and $E_i$ amongst themselves. In total, this gives us $4! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! = 96$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

4! ways to correctly arrange the S's , 2 ways for the E's and C's. So there are $4!\times 2\times 2 = 96$ ways to rearrange those letters such that it spells successes (out of 9! ways to arrange a 9 letter word, if you want to make it into a probability).